# How to access final GraphQL-Reponse in nest.js with interceptor

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

I have implemented a `LoggingInterceptor` which should be able to access the final GraphQL-Response with its data- and error properties + the original request body and the authenticated user, which has been added to the request by `AuthGuard` before.*(EDIT: Partially solved by @jay-mcdoniel: `user` and `body` are accessible through `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext()`)*

Indeed the Interceptor just provides one fully resolved GraphQL-Object.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(tap(
      (allData) => console.log(allData),
      (error)=> console.log(error)));
  }
}
```

This is my Interceptor-Class. It's just calling the RxJS-Operator `tap` to log the current values of the observable.

If I run the following GraphQL-Request...

```
mutation {
  login(data: { username: "admin", password: "123456" }) {
    id
    username
    token
  }
}
```

... my server answers correctly with the following response-body:

```
{
  "data": {
    "login": {
      "id": "6f40be3b-cda9-4e6d-97ce-ced3787e9974",
      "username": "admin",
      "token": "someToken"
    }
  }
}
```

But the content of `allData` which get's logged to console by my interceptor is the following:

```
{
  id: '6f40be3b-cda9-4e6d-97ce-ced3787e9974',
  isAdmin: true,
  username: 'admin',
  firstname: null,
  lastname: null,
  email: null,
  created: 2019-07-05T15:11:31.606Z,
  token: 'someToken'
}
```

Instead I would like to see the information of the real response-body.

I have additionally tried to access the HttpResponse by `context.switchToHttp().getResponse()`. But this only contains the parameters of the mutation-login-method:

```
{
  data: [Object: null prototype] { username: 'admin', password: '123456' }
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

`console.log(GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext());`
prints (still no GraphQL-ResponseBody):

```
{
  headers: {
    /*...*/
  },
  user: /*...*/,
  body: {
    operationName: null,
    variables: {},
    query: 'mutation {\n  login(data: {username: "admin", password: ' +
      '"123456"}) {\n    token\n    id\n    username\n    isAdmin\n  }\n' +
      '}\n'
  },
  res: ServerResponse {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: true,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      timeout: 120000,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 566,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        /*...*/
      },
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    connection: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      timeout: 120000,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 566,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 3273,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 567,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 566
      },
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _header: null,
    _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
    _sent100: false,
    _expect_continue: false,
    req: IncomingMessage {
      /*...*/
    },
    locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
    [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
    [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      'x-powered-by': [Array],
      'access-control-allow-origin': [Array]
    }
  },
  _extensionStack: GraphQLExtensionStack { extensions: [ [CacheControlExtension] ] }
}
```

Comment: I'm not even able to print anything with this in case of graphql query, however this is working fine with regular controller calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's how I did that in my Logging Interceptor

```
    @Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // default REST Api
    if (context.getType() === 'http') {
     ...
     ...
    }

    // Graphql
    if (context.getType<GqlContextType>() === 'graphql') {
      const gqlContext = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      const info = gqlContext.getInfo();
      const res: Response = gqlContext.getContext().res;
      // Get user that sent request
      const userId = context.getArgByIndex(2).req.user.userId;
      const parentType = info.parentType.name;
      const fieldName = info.fieldName;
      const body = info.fieldNodes[0]?.loc?.source?.body;
      const message = `GraphQL - ${parentType} - ${fieldName}`;

      // Add request ID,so it can be tracked with response
      const requestId = uuidv4();
      // Put to header, so can attach it to response as well
      res.set('requestId', requestId);

      const trace = {
        userId,
        body
      };

      this.logger.info(`requestId: ${requestId}`, {
        context: message,
        trace
      });
      
      return next.handle().pipe(
        tap({
          next: (val: unknown): void => {
            this.logNext(val, context);
          }
        })
      );
    }
    return next.handle();
  }

  /**
   * Method to log response message
   */
  private logNext(body: unknown, context: ExecutionContext): void {
    // default REST Api
    if (context.getType() === 'http') {
      ...
      ...
    }

    if (context.getType<GqlContextType>() === 'graphql') {
      const gqlContext = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      const info = gqlContext.getInfo();
      const parentType = info.parentType.name;
      const fieldName = info.fieldName;
      const res: Response = gqlContext.getContext().res;
      const message = `GraphQL - ${parentType} - ${fieldName}`;

      // Remove secure fields from request body and headers
      const secureBody = secureReqBody(body);

      const requestId = res.getHeader('requestId');

      // Log trace message
      const trace = {
        body: { ...secureBody }
      };
      this.logger.info(`requestId: ${requestId}`, {
        context: message,
        trace
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The interceptor is actually called before and after the response, or it should be at least, so that you can have pre-request logic (request in) and post-request logic (response out). You should be able to do all pre-request processing before you call `next.hanlde()` and then you should be able to use the `RxJS Observable operators` such as `tap` or `map` after a `pipe()` call. Your `allData` variable should have all the information from the request/response, and you can even use the `context` variable for getting even more information.

What does `allData` currently print for you? Have you tried `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().req` or `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().res`? These are shown being used in the `Guards` documentation to get the request and response objects like you would with a normal HTTP call.

Comment: Thx so far! `allData` contains the requested data you would find inside the data property of the graphql reponse plus all properties that got resolved by typeorm relations (even that ones which aren't present in the graphql request). That's why I called it `allData`. It's not a partial object. `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext()` works for reading `context.body.query ` and `context.user`. But it is still not possible to access `graphqlResponse` because it is not part of the context.

Comment: I have added some more examples to my question and removed unnecessary information.

Comment: To be honest, I think the response body you are looking for is something that Nest handles under the hood and isn't quite exposed to us without really getting into the internals. I'm trying to read through the source code, but I can't promise much will come out of it

Comment: I have totally forgot to post the log of `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext()`. I have updated my question with the information.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing some digging both with my GraphQL code and with the source code, and I'm pretty sure the `GraphQLRespnse` you are looking for is taken care of under the hood and not exposed, but without 100% understanding it I couldn't say.

Comment: Hello there, This **GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().req** works fine and returns whole request, But **GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().res** returns undefined, Any Solution for it?

Comment: @AmmarAhmed do you have the `context` set correctly to set up the `req` and `res` in your `GraphqlModule.forRoot/Async`?

Comment: HI @JayMcDoniel I am setting **context** like this `GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    }),`.
How I can add res there?

Comment: `context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })`